# how call api react js on close window browser in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Where do I need to make an API call in react js when the browser is closed?

I am using "onbeforeunload" but its working to call the function and that time is working but when i am trying to call the API the time is not working. when the browser is closed at that point, I need to make an API call in React JS?

Comment: Are you trying to call an api and close the browser at the same time ?

Comment: yes i am trying to call an api and close the browser at the same time api call men's i am   send data by useing api

Comment: Call API first on success of API close the browser, that will solve your problem

Comment: I want to call API on window close not  before close window

Comment: you cannot do that once window is closed your code will loose the control of app or browser, What i am assuming is API call is to logout or clear some data, so you can call the API and close the window that will be fine

Comment: you men's I can't send  API response on window close ?

Comment: Yes, you can't do anything on window close, whatever you want to do on window close should be done before and asynchronously